# Facing Application crashes (Beginner)

Tags: java, android

I tried my best but unable to resolve this issue, I tried debugging nothing happened, tried making new project same error. Till afternoon project was working perfectly fine but then it is giving an error just tried to update UI of the Android app:

```
E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE) 
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nodemcu.controlnodemcu, PID: 6681
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.nodemcu.nodemcucontroller.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.<init>(MainActivity.java:80)
                      at com.example.nodemcu.nodemcucontroller.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.<init>(MainActivity.java:68)
                      at com.example.nodemcu.nodemcucontroller.MainActivity.buttonClick(MainActivity.java:63)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Application terminated.
```

**Libraries imported:**

```
package com.example.nodemcu.nodemcucontroller;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
```

**Code For MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final Context context = this;
private EditText ipAddress;
private Button ledOn, ledOff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ipAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_ip);
    ledOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ledOn);
    ledOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ledOff);

}
public void buttonClick(View view) {
    String ledStatus;

    if (ipAddress.getText().toString().equals(""))
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter the ip address...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    else {
        if (view == ledOn)
            ledStatus = "1";

        else
            ledStatus = "0";

        String serverAdress = ipAddress.getText().toString() + ":" + "80";
        HttpRequestTask requestTask = new HttpRequestTask(serverAdress);
        requestTask.execute(ledStatus);
    }
}

private static class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private String serverAdress;
    private String serverResponse = "";
    AlertDialog dialog;
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;
    HttpRequestTask(MainActivity context){
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }
    private HttpRequestTask(String serverAdress) {
        this.serverAdress = serverAdress;

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityReference.get())
                .setTitle("HTTP Response from Ip Address:")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        dialog.setMessage("Data sent , waiting response from server...");

        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.show();

        String val = params[0];
        final String url = "http://" + serverAdress + "/led/" + val;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
            getRequest.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        }
        return serverResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        dialog.setMessage(serverResponse);

        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Sending data to server, please wait...");

        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.show();
       }
   }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_ip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/ip_address"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ledOff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:text="@string/led_off" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ledOn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:text="@string/led_on" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm seeing a null pointer exception in your stack trace.  How did you try debugging?  Did you add a breakpoint to the `onCreate` method of every activity?  If so, are you telling us that none of those breakpoints even get hit?

Comment: I am just a beginner so don't know much so i just did Debug app :(

Comment: Check Logcat and then add some breakpoints to your code.  If you don't know how to do these things, then read some of the better questions here on SO about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete Edit**

As per this line in your crash logs

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference at com.example.nodemcu.nodemcucontroller.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.
```

Problem is your `activityReference` is null while creating alert dialog.

You have `two` constructors inside your `HttpRequestTask`.

**EDIT**

Change your `HttpRequestTask` constructor like this:

```
 private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    private HttpRequestTask(String serverAdress, MainActivity context) {
        this.serverAdress = serverAdress;
        this.activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityReference.get())
                .setTitle("HTTP Response from Ip Address:")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create();
    }
```

Comment: So how to over come on it?

Comment: Thank you for your response i tried it is giving me error on getApplicationContext()
error is:
Non-static method 'getApplicationContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Edited my answer. Didn't saw you had  `HttpRequestTask` static

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Context context = this;
private EditText ipAddress;
private Button ledOn, ledOff;
private String ledStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ipAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_ip);
   ledOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ledOn);
   ledOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ledOff);

   if (ipAddress.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter the ip address...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       } else {
         ledOn.setOnclicklistener(this);
         ledOff.setOnclicklistener(this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()){
       case R.id.ledOn:
         ledStatus = "1";
       break;
       case R.id.ledOff:
         if (ledStatus == "1") { ledStatus = "0"; }
       break;
    }
   // do your async task here
}
}
```

The buttons should work now without errors. DOn't know about your async task but that should work too depending on if it's receiving input from `ledOn` or `ledOff` buttons, then you can put the code there, otherwise, it's fine. Try this way.

Comment: But if i will delete that how would i be able to do the task i wanted to perform.

Comment: Have you tried exactly how I had written it and it didnt work?

Comment: I tried still facing same issue it is like due to AsyncTask :(